# C integer and float division output

Tags: c, integer, division

Can somebody explain the output of the following code: 
http://cpp.sh/9dy44

Why is the last line always 0.17?

```
float a = 17, b = 100;

printf("%f\n", 17/100);
printf("%f\n", a/b);
printf("%f\n", 17/b);
printf("%f\n", 17.0f/b);
printf("%f\n", a/100);
printf("%f\n", a/100.0f);
printf("%f\n", 5/100);
```

output

```
0.000000
0.170000
0.170000
0.170000
0.170000
0.170000
0.170000
```

Comment: UB here `... "%f\n", 17/100);` allready all the rest is (bad) luck,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing int as float in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607628/printing-int-as-float-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `Undefined Behaviour` , don't try to understand why this is happening , because as the name suggests , it is `undefined` !. The undefined behaviour happens because you are trying to print a double but you're passing two integers . Note that you are also getting a warning :

> 14:25: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

Change last line to this:

```
    printf("%f\n", 5.0/100);
```

And it will work as expected .

Comment: I was expecting the output of last line would bei 0, is there an explanation why it sticks with the 0.17?

Comment: Each comipler you will use may have different behaviour , one will print 0 , the other 0.17, and another one will print 2. Why ? Becuase it is undefined .

Comment: if you're instested in knowing more - google : `C Undefined behaviour` , there are plenty articles on this subject .

Comment: okay thanks so far... i was just wondering why the behavior was so different between the first and last printf

Comment: It is detrimental to tell somebody “don’t try to understand.” While behavior not defined by the C standard may be perplexing and is not strictly needed to write a working C program, understanding it nonetheless has benefits. It provides insights into how compilers, processors, and other system components work, and that insight both helps diagnose bugs and learn about things outside of pure C. In this case, the floating-point value left in the register for passing floating-point arguments by printing `a/b` or `17.0f/b` remains in the register for subsequent calls to `printf`, so it is reused.

Answer (score 0):

Because You are dividing integers and than trying to print (the integer result as) a float value

**Try This**

```
// Example program
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 17, b = 100;

    printf("%f\n", 17.0/100);
    printf("%f\n", a/b);
    printf("%f\n", 17/b);
    printf("%f\n", 17.0f/b);
    printf("%f\n", a/100);
    printf("%f\n", a/100.0f);
    printf("%f\n", 5.00/100);

    return 0;
}
```