# How to can I catch missing parameters when using printf?

Tags: c

In the program below, there is a parameter missing in the call to function `printf`, which will cause undified behaviour at run time, but no warning is given when compiling.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;

    printf("%d:this is for test:%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I catch this error at compile time?

Comment: Why would you skip a parameter?

Comment: You avoid missing parameters by providing all necessary parameters. Also `void main()` should be `int main()` in C++ or `int main(void)` in C (which also means you should decide which language you use)

Comment: Use a compiler that displays a warning.

Comment: Which compiler and level of warnings?

Comment: Are you talking about C or C++? They're different languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get printf style compile-time warnings or errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105114/how-to-get-printf-style-compile-time-warnings-or-errors)

Comment: @Marievi: You shouldn't, of course. The question is about catching this programming error at complie time, not at run time. (I don't know why this snarky comment gets so much approval.)

Comment: @MOehm This question isn't written very clearly.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? This will make a big difference to the warnings that you may get.

Comment: @MOehm Not at all snarky. I just did not understand the question and asked to clarify.

Comment: @Marievi: Fair enough. Sorry about the comment.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Why you are using "%s"? Here no need to use "%s" as it is used to print string value.
For integer value you only need "%d".

Run your code like this.

```
#include<stdio.>
int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  printf("%d: this is for test", a);
}
```

Thanks.

[EDIT]

It's undefined if you pass fewer arguments than the format specifiers. Compiler is not required to produce any errors on undefined behaviour.

Although, most compilers would do. GCC, for example, produces the following for your code:

```
warning: too few arguments for format
```

when compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 file.c
```

Comment: You missed the point of the question: it's an example of accidentally forgetting to provide an argument for the placeholder. The question is how to catch such accidental omissions in real code.

Comment: It's undefined if you pass fewer arguments than the format specifiers. Compiler is not required to produce any errors on undefined behaviour.

Although, most compilers would do. GCC, for example, produces the following for your code:
"warning: too few arguments for format"
when compiled with:
"gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 file.c"

Comment: ...plus this wont compile, there is a `h` missing

Comment: your comment could be an answer, though there is already an answer suggesting to use `-Wall`

Comment: @Burhan Which is what your answer should state instead of "you've made a mistake." The OP **knows** they've made it, and ask how to get the compiler to catch it.

Answer (score 2):

compile with `gcc -Wall`
for this situation warning be like: `warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]`

Answer (score -6):

The error is because in

printf("%d:this is for test:%s",a);

You need to pass two parameters, one to %d and another to %s.
So, now a will be substituted in the place of "%d", you are not passing anything to be substituted in the place of %s.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the OP is aware that this is an error. The question is how to catch this programming error at complie time.